# SQL Find parents grandparents of specific child

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

So, I basically have two tables Dogs and Litter

Table Dogs:

```
ID(PK)        Litter_ID       Name
---------------------------------  
1             null        Fido

2             null        Freda

3             11          Pedro

4             11          John

5             22          Maria

6             33          Billy
7
```

Table Litter:

```
Litter_ID (PK)------Father_id---------- Mother_id

11---------------------1-----------------2

33---------------------4-----------------5
```

How do I find all father mothers and grandparents of a specific dog?

This gives me only the parents, but how about the grandparents if there are some?

```
SELECT Dogs.id, Name, Father_id, Mother_id
FROM Dogs, Litter
WHERE Dogs.litter_id = litter.litter_id AND dogs.id = 6;
```

So if I search for Billy, I should get Maria and John and then John's parents Fido and Freda.

I'd appreciate some help

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (Postgres, MySQL, Sql Server, Oracle...) ? Please add a tag for whatever system you are on. You will most likely want to use recursive sql to solve for this (although another join will give you grandparent without going recursive), and each RDBMS has a slightly different syntax for recursive logic.

Comment: In your example Billy's parents are John (4) and Maria (5). But you description says Pedro and Maria.

Comment: This could be handled with no recursive query, since you know that there are a limited number of parent hierarchies to go up.

Comment: Sorry, for the typos, I'm a bit tired. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: WHICH DBMS?  The syntax is different from one dbms to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using SQL Server, the following should work.

```
create table Dogs (ID int, Litter_ID int, Name varchar(10));
create table Litter (Litter_ID int, Father_ID int, Mother_ID int);

insert into Dogs values (1, null, 'Fido')
insert into Dogs values (2, null, 'Freda')
insert into Dogs values (3, 11, 'Pedro')
insert into Dogs values (4, 11, 'John')
insert into Dogs values (5, 22, 'Maria')
insert into Dogs values (6, 33, 'Billy')

insert into Litter values (11, 1, 2)
insert into Litter values (33, 4, 5)

SELECT
    Parents.Name AS Parent,
    GrandParents.Name AS GrandParent
FROM Dogs
inner join Litter on Dogs.Litter_ID = Litter.Litter_ID
inner join Dogs Parents on Parents.ID = Litter.Father_ID or Parents.ID = Litter.Mother_ID
left join Litter ParentsLitter on ParentsLitter.Litter_ID = Parents.Litter_ID
left join Dogs GrandParents on GrandParents.ID = ParentsLitter.Father_ID or GrandParents.ID = ParentsLitter.Mother_ID
WHERE dogs.id = 6;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it

Comment: This crashed the database, I'm using SQL wizard, but I solved it thanks.